# Получить данные с помощью скрипта python с роутера mikrotik

Tags: python-3.x, mikrotik

Пишу скрипт работы взаимодействия python и роутера микротик, была необходимость только отправлять команды на выполнения роутеру микротик с помощью paramiko по SSH, все хорошо работает. Но вот поступила новая необходимость брать информацию с роутера микротик.
Подскажите пожалуйста какой командой я могу получить информацию с микротика и записать в переменную? например имя микротика /system identity print

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте [API](https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:API). Пример реализации на Python можно найти в [официальной Wiki](https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:API_Python3)

Сама команда будет выглядеть так:

```
/system/identity/print
```

Так же можно использовать готовые библиотеки типа [librouteros](https://pypi.org/project/librouteros/).